# Размещение содержимого div по центру

Tags: html, css

Хочу разместить содержимое блока по центру, допустим это горизонтальное меню, как сделать чтобы не указывать ширину блоков, а они подстраивались автоматом под ширину содержимого

то есть:

```
<ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Item 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Что бы не указывать ширину ни у ul ни у блоков li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #666;
  text-align: center; // центруем строчные элементы
}

ul {
  display: inline-block; /* правращаем в строчный (строчноблочный) элемент,
  что бы сработало выравнивание и блок ужался до размеров контента */
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: left; // возвращаем стандартно позиционирование текста у левого края
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
      <li>
          <a href="#">Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#">Item 22</a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#">Item 333</a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#">Item 4444</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: а ширину элемента li обязательно указывать? они же разные могут быть по ширине

Comment: не, не обязательно, задал для красоты (плюс сразу не глянул, что у них есть контент внутри и он и так их раздвинет, убрал)

Comment: Все что нужно понимать в этом варианте - первые 2 свойства с комментариями, остальное просто "стили для красоты"

Comment: Да все классно) спасибо большое

Answer (score 4):

```css
ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
ul li{
    list-style: none;    
}
ul a{
    padding: 5px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
ul a:hover{
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item long text 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item 4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: а flex это новое что то? как оно работает?

Comment: да новое, но уже имеет хорошую поддержку браузеров - http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/

Comment: Ну, назвать flex "новым" уже сложно, главное что отталкивает - не поодерживается на ie9 (на практике не такой уж и редкий/старый браузер). По этому всегда когда использую flex стараюсь делать проверку и альтернативную верстку, если проверка не пройдена. Да и как правило без flex'ов можно обойтись

Comment: @MedvedevDev . все зависит от требований по кроссбраузерности. Если  ie9 не нужен, используйте  flex. + ie9 можно отдельно задать стили

Comment: @soledar10, я предпочитаю использовать классические методы, если без flex не могу придумать - тогда пускаю в ход его, но всегда перестраховываюсь с альтернативными стилями, даже если в ТЗ стоит ie10+